# Jquery - Apply class based on contents of <a>

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal navigation menu which I can edit the source of, my only option is to add classes dynamically when it loads through JQUERY.

Imagine I have 3 tabs:

```
Home, Profile, Blog
```

Each with a link like so:

```
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
```

Is it possible for JQUERY to look between the `<a> </a>` tags and find the text (E.g. Home) and use that text as the class?

So my `<a href="home.html">` becomes: `<a class="Home" href="home.html">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a").each(function () {
  var self = $(this);
  self.addClass(self.text());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`:contains`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) if you know what you're looking for:

```
$('a :contains(Home)').addClass('home');
```

I think this would be more robust:

```
$('a.nav').each(function() {

    // add class with name of the link's text
    $(this).addClass($(this).text());
});
```

Assuming you give your navigation links the class `nav`.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
$("a:contains('Home')").removeClass().addClass("Home");
```

Comment: Karim79's 2nd example if probably more what you're after.