# Adding class based on contents of link text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I found a nice [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624014/819276) here on Stack which grabs the text from a link and appends it to the a tag as a class:

```
$('a.nav').each(function() {

    // add class with name of the link's text
    $(this).addClass($(this).text());
});
```

It works great except that I have a list of linked search results that output `(numbers), e.g. (19)` after the link text.

So the structure of my HTML after the JQuery above is applied is as such:

```
<li><a class="Basic page (1)" href="#">Basic page (1)</a></li>
<li><a class="Blog (19)" href="#">Blog (19)</a></li>
<li><a class="News (4)" href="#">News (4)</a></li>
```

As you can see, it's not ideal. If possible, I'd like to at least get rid of the numbers in parenths i.e. `(1)`, `(19)` etc... and then put dashes and with the text and lower case. Note this is for a faceted search result so the links will never all be together or in the same order.  I am simply trying to apply dynamic classes based on the link text name so I can do other things down the road in a theming realm.

so this:

```
<li><a class="Basic page (1)" href="#">Basic page (1)</a></li>
```

... would become this:

```
<li><a class="basic-page" href="#">Basic page (1)</a></li>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need this? It sounds very convoluted. You could use the `index` of the `li` element to identify them instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the issue is that they are search results for a faceted search so will never all appear together or in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFXcg/)

```
$(function() {
    $.each($('ul li a'), function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        this.className = $.trim(text.replace(/\(\d*\)/g, '').toLowerCase()).replace(/\s/, '_');
    });
});
```

Comment: There were some great answers here, but I like this one! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

some basic regex will get the format you're looking for.

```
$('a.nav').each(function() {

    // add class with name of the link's text
    $(this).addClass($(this).text()
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/(\s\(\d+\))/, '') // replaces ' ([digit(s)])'
        .replace(/\s+/g, '-')); // replaces spaces with dashes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a small function [here](http://dense13.com/blog/2009/05/03/converting-string-to-slug-javascript/). With it's help I guess below code will work for you;

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav">Basic page (1)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"class="nav">Blog (19)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"class="nav">News (4)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function string_to_slug(str) {
  str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
  str = str.toLowerCase();

  // remove accents, swap ñ for n, etc
  var from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
  var to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";
  for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
  }

  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '') // remove invalid chars
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // collapse whitespace and replace by -
    .replace(/-+/g, '-'); // collapse dashes

  return str;
}

jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.nav').each(function() {

        // add class with name of the link's text
        $(this).addClass(string_to_slug($(this).text()));
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CjdsG/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.nav').each(function() {
    var oSelf = $(this);
    var sClass = oSelf.html()
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/(\w)(\W\([0-9]+\))/, '$1')
        .replace(' ', '-');
    oSelf.addClass(sClass);
});
```